# How to interpret this "hammer on" in this guitar tab?

Tags: guitar, tablature

Does anyone know how I would interpret this hammer on in the guitar tab seen in the image?

[image]

I would usually read this as "play the third string on the fourth fret, hammer on 5, hammer on 4" but this doesn't make sense in this case since you would usually hammer on higher up the neck in relation to the previous note hammered on.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It’s a hammer-on fret 4 to 5 immediately followed by a [pull-off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-off#Performance_and_effect) fret 5 to 4. You just pick the note once, but do a hammer-on followed by a pull-off. Hammer-ons and pull-offs both use the same slur notation (the curved line); therefore, the only way to distinguish between them, is whether you are going from a lower-to-higher or higher-to-lower fret.

And yes, you can have multiple hammer-ons *and* pull-offs under one slur. This hammer-on, pull-off back to the first note, would be termed a **mordent** in classical terminology. If you repeatedly alternate between two notes under a slur, this would be a trill:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Bob's answer, it's a slur mark. That means the three notes are played 'in one breath' - without any more than one pluck of the right hand. That's **legato** playing.

As Bob says, it's usually executed by *plucking* the first note, *hammering-on* the second (one fret higher), then *pulling-off* with the same finger that hammered-on, back to the first note pitch.

That's the usual way to play slurs on guitar. However, another way is to *slide* - where the first note is plucked, then the second is slid to, then the third slid back to. That way, the transition between notes is smooth, which is, after all, what slurring is supposed to do.

So, two ways in which to play a 'slur' in guitar music. Often, in tab, it's indicated, but not always - sometimes left to the discretion of the performer.

Comment: Slides are usually indicated with a straight diagonal line, so the notation is not ambiguous.

Comment: @J... - in the absence of anything except a slur mark, either is an option.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. A slur always means a hammer/pull on plucked string instruments.  A slide is always marked with a [glissando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glissando).

Comment: @J... - on tab, true, but on real music...

Comment: Maybe you should click that link... either that or we have a serious difference of opinion about what "real music" means.